# Easy way to change compression level of a zip file

Tags: linux, zip, compression

On linux, is there an easy way to recompress a zip file (changing compression-level) with preserving as most meta-data as possible (timestamps etc.)?

Comment: To clarify, when you say zip file you are referring to compression with the actual `zip` command, correct?

Comment: @Peschke Consider that we have an existing zip file with an unknown compression level. Now we'd like to 'change' the compression level of this file, e.g. to store-only (most likely, a decompression/recompression is required for this). I'm interested whether there's is any application/script which can do this as easy as possible, possibly by not changing any file meta data. It must not neccessarly use the 'zip' command.

Comment: Unzip should preserve timestamps by default so you can probably just unzip -> zip it with the parameters you want. You could always create a script or alias to do this as a one-liner.

Comment: _MRalwasser_, when you respond to a Comment, please click on edit and expand or refine the original post so all may see the latest information. Please do so, and advise which filesystem is in use, for different filesystems have different metadata available, and all so not store them in i-nodes. http://www.lostsaloon.com/technology/how-to-view-all-details-or-metadata-of-a-file-in-linux-command-line/ and https://www.cs.columbia.edu/~smb/classes/s06-4118/l21.pdf may be helpful to you in understanding what you can access beyond the date and time of original archive creation.

Answer (score 0):

Any script which expands an archive back to its original collection of files, and then re-archives them with your preferred parameters, would work, so long as you collect the metadata (in your case, the original date and time of the first archive), then use [touch](https://ss64.com/bash/touch.html) to change the date and time of the new archive to match.